# Datatable for ARM architecture?

Tags: datatable, arm, apple-m1, py-datatable

```
import datatable as dt
```

Throws an `ImportError`:

```
ImportError: dlopen(miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datatable/lib/_datatable.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: 'miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datatable/lib/_datatable.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))
```

Is there an ARM version in development?

Comment: I'd suggest that for this particular question, you should post it as a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues) or on the [discussions](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/discussions) page

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved in https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/3003#issuecomment-866386747

Running `` lipo -info `which clang++ `` will return
`Architectures in the fat file: /usr/bin/clang++ are: x86_64 arm64e` so you need to switch to arm64e only.

To switch to arm64 for compilation, run
`env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh --login`

https://vineethbharadwaj.medium.com/m1-mac-switching-terminal-between-x86-64-and-arm64-e45f324184d9 details how to make aliases in your .zshrc for quickly switching between x86 and arm64.